# Pandas - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building a function that uses conditional masks in order to filter a given dataframe, where all arguments must be initialized with `None`, like so:

```
def filter_dataframe(self, dataframe, position_id=None, team_id=None, home=None, window=None):

        df = dataframe.copy()
        now = self.get_now()
        
        masks = {
            "mask1": [position_id is not None, df[df["position_id"] == position_id]],
            "mask2": [team_id is not None, df[df["team_id"] == team_id]],
            "mask3": [home == "Home", df[df["home_dummy"] == 1.0]],
            "mask4": [home == "Away", df[df["home_dummy"] == 0.0]],
            "mask5": [window is not None, df[df["gameweek"].between((now - window),now)]]            
            }
        for value in masks.values():
            if value[0]:
                df = value[1]
            return df
```

---

The problem here is that when arg 'window' is initialized with `None`, python throws the error because it is part of an operation:

```
"mask5": [window is not None, df[df["gameweek"].between((now - window),now)]] 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

---

How do I handle the case when window is `None` in (now - window) in order to avoid this error?

Comment: You might need to handle the case when `window` is None in `now - window`.

Comment: yes... but how?

Comment: You didn't explain what you want to do. Why asking how to others?

Comment: The question is obviously how to handle that error. It is in the question. But if it's not clear enough, I've edited the question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to add an if check for the window in the expression that is evaluated upon defining the masks variable, eg.

```
"mask5": [window is not None, df[df["gameweek"].between((now - window if window is not None else 0),now)]]
```

A better solution would be to convert the mask operations into lambdas to prevent unnecessary eager computation.

```
"mask5": [window is not None, lambda: df[df["gameweek"].between((now - window,now)]]
```

Then you can call the lambda functions in your for loop if their respective condition matches

```
df = value[1]()
```